# IE 9 font width rendering

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am building a carousel that shows 3 items of news on a website. it shows the news title and the first 150 characters of the news story, all items in the carousel have to be the same height so i have set each news item to height:182px; width:210px;

It all looks good in every browser apart from IE 9 as it seems to render the fonts a little wider than all other browsers, so because all items have a set height and width, the text in IE 9 goes onto 4 lines instead of the 3 lines all other browsers use. Then this knocks everything else out of place.

So I am wondering if there is something that can be done to make the text the same as all other browsers?

Thanks for any help.

J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found the problem in case anyone else has the same issue.

Not sure if anyone else does this but it's what caused the problem.

in my css on body I usually put font-size:64.5% so that any em fonts I use after that are basically a 10th of the pixel size, so 14px would be a font size of 1.4em etc etc...

but doing so seem to make IE9 up scale the font slightly when using 1.1em, so i've now put the body css to font-size:100% then used http://pxtoem.com/ to find the specific em font sizes and all seems to be working well in all browsers...hope this helps someone else :)

This may also be of some use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#using_spp_on_your_site

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this too and it's quite an irritation. I've had to create css fixes for things I'm working on. Why is it IE can never get it right! It slows down development time no end.

Comment: what css fixes are there? i was thinking of using conditional statements and making the font-weight lighter for IE9 or something but i can't seem to to make the font lighter.

Comment: @Simon, this is not an answer to the question.